# MongoDB Agregation of arbitrary number of properties

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have documents:

```js
{
    "_id": "XXXX"
    "date": ISODate(...)
    "metrics":{
        "lang": {
            "en": 2,
            "es": 10,
            "ru": 2
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And I want sum of each lang. In lang object can be one or many langs. So how can I achieve this with aggregation-framework. Result can look like this:

```js
{
    "_id": "XXX"
    "sums": {
        "en": 10,
        "es": 23,
        "ru": 4,
        "cs": 1,
        ...
   }
}
```

I think I can use some $unwind and $addToSet params but I'm new in Mongo. Thanks for answer.

Comment: You can't do it generically, you'll have to explicitly name each possible lang.

Comment: Yeah, I think it needs change structure

Comment: You lang is not an array, so you will not be doing an unwind. Moreover you should be looking to make your lang as an array of docs. lang: [ { name: en, count: 10}, {name: es, count:2} ]